# SharePoint 2007 user migration: User was removed from SharePoint groups

Tags: sharepoint, moss, stsadm

I'm responsible for migrating users from domain A to domain B for a SharePoint 2007 MOSS farm. I'm using stsadm -o migrateuser command.

The problem is, after I run the command for 2 testing users, 1 user was removed from every groups he was in before. The other one is working fine so far.

I would like to understand the process of the command and how come it removed the user from groups.

For more information: In the farm, I have some other decommissioned applications and their content databases were set to read-only. The only difference when I run the command for 2 accounts is with the working account, I set all these database to "read/write" mode before running the script. Is that possible that the "Read-only" databases caused the problem?

Comment: To be clear, with your two test users, did you run the stsadm command to migrate User 1 to User 2, or did you run the stsadm command twice, once for oldDomain\user1 to newDomain\user1 and once for oldDomain\user2 to newDomain\user2?

Comment: @Thriggle: Thanks for your attention. I ran 2 commands to migrate from oldDomain\user1 to newDomain\user1 and oldDomain\user2 to newDomain\user2